# Why isn't this index taken into account?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have the following query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
  [Extent1].[EspecialId] AS [EspecialId], 
  [Extent1].[FeriadoId] AS [FeriadoId], 
  [Extent1].[EspecialGrupo] AS [EspecialGrupo], 
  [Extent1].[EspecialCreadoEn] AS [EspecialCreadoEn], 
  [Extent1].[EspecialActualizadoEn] AS [EspecialActualizadoEn], 
  [Extent1].[EspecialEliminadoEn] AS [EspecialEliminadoEn]
FROM [dbo].[FeriadoEspecial] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[FeriadoId] = 565
```

[FeriadoEspecial] table has this structure:

[image]

Which has these indices:

[image]

PK_FeriadoEspecial is the default index created for the primary key. I have added a new index called IX_FeriadoEspecialFeriado.

When running the query, showing the actual execution plan, this is shown:

[image]

Why an index scan is being performed, across the primary key index, instead of an index seek through IX_FeriadoEspecialFeriado? Is there a way to solve this to optimize the query?

Comment: Because it doesn't include any of the other columns in your query.  An non-clustered index that only contains the column `FeriadoId` isn't much use when you want data from other columns.

Comment: @Larnu But I am also getting value from FeriadoId column, ain't I?

Comment: But what about, `EspecialGrupo`, `EspecialCreadoEn`, `EspecialActualizadoEn`, and `EspecialEliminadoEn`. Again, they aren't in your index, so the RDBMS determined a scan of the clsutered index, which includes every column, would be better than reading both the index and the `CLUSTERED` index.

Comment: How many rows are in the table and how many rows have the value 565? You could force the index to be used with a hint - which will require bookmark lookup(s) - and compare the logical reads of each